# Accessing a property on a method which returns a Model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a Post model which has a function as follows:

```
namespace App;

use App\Category;

class Post extends Model

{
    public function category()
   {

    return $this->hasOne(Category::class);

   }

}
```

And my Category Model looks like this

```
namespace App;

use App\Post;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {

    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);

    }
}
```

In my view, I want to get access to the **name** field on the category for each post.

I assumed I would have access to that model and could therefore get it by doing this in my blade file:

```
{{ $post->category()->name }}
```

$post is correct, I have access to other properties but this throws the error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$name
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should access it as an attribute:

```
{{ $post->category->name }}
```

The function category() should be defined in Post model as:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

If `category_id` has another name, just change it in the parameter.

Comment: This throws "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

Comment: `Post` has a `category_id` field? Or `Category` has a `post_id` field?

Comment: The field is just called category. But having been through and changed it to category_id I am getting the error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.post_id' "

Comment: Categories don't have a post id also. just in case this will affect this

Comment: Still getting the "Trying to get property of non-object" error but I suspect I have set up my Eloquent relationships completely wrong. My categories table doesn't have an post_id saved. I wanted to just reference the category names by the id and not have a list of posts which belong to them. Is this possible? :(

Comment: If I change it to what you have suggested above and var_dump a single $post->category I just get the category id. I must be missing something to access the entire object but I am new to Laravel.

Comment: If you want that each `Post` has a `Category`, you should define a `category_id` in `Post` model and create a function with a `belongsTo` relationship. It is important to set the category id in a field named `category_id`, because this follows the convention.

Comment: Regarding the problem `$post->category` returning just the id, maybe it is because the function has the same name as the field. So, try to change the name of the function, for example: `public function catTest()`, and then try to call `$post->catTest->name`.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do this:

```
$category=$post->category;
$cat_name=$category->name;
```

also if you only want the name field of the category you can use :

```
$cat_name=$post->category()->get(['name']);
```